# How to Make Custom Strongly Typed Extension Method in MVC Razor without using Tag Builder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to MVC Framework, so please be gentle on me. I want to make strongly typed custom extension method without using Tag Builder class. I have been searching the web for an example
with explanation, but i'm unable to find any solution. please help me.
The code is below for custom extension method, please tell me how to convert it into strongly typed.

```
public static MvcHtmlString DateOfBirth(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        var text = @"<div>
    <select style=""width: 40px"">";
    for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
    {
        if (i < 10)
        {
            text += "<option>" + 0 + +i + "</option>";
        }
        else
        {
            text += "<option>" + i + "</option>";
        }
    }
text += "</select>";
text += "<select style=\"width: 40px\">";
    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        if (i < 10)
        {
            text += "<option>" + 0 + +i + "</option>";
        }
        else
        {
            text += "<option>" + i + "</option>";
        }

    }
 text += "</select>";
 text += "<select style=\"width: 60px\">";
    var date = System.DateTime.Now.Year;
    for (int i = 1950; i <= date; i++)
    {
        text += "<option>"+i+"</option>";
    }
 text += "</select>";
text += "</div>";

        return new MvcHtmlString(text);

    }
```

Comment: You want the strongly typed HtmlHelper if I'm understanding correctly?

Comment: Yes, that is the requirement.

Comment: ask to sunny. genius is sitting nearby you !

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you wanna use a TagBuilder when this class is designed exactly for that purpose? You prefer writing some tag soup? Don't.

Here:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString DateOfBirthFor<TModel>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, DateTime>> ex
    )
    {
        var days = Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Select(x => new SelectListItem 
        { 
            Value = x.ToString(),
            Text = x.ToString()
        });
        var months = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.ToString(),
            Text = x.ToString()
        });
        var years = Enumerable.Range(1950, DateTime.Now.Year - 1949).Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.ToString(),
            Text = x.ToString()
        });

        var result = new TagBuilder("div");
        DateTime dob = (DateTime)ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(ex, html.ViewData).Model;

        result.InnerHtml = string.Concat(
            html.DropDownList("Day", new SelectList(days, "Value", "Text", dob.Day), new { width = "40px" }).ToHtmlString(),
            html.DropDownList("Month", new SelectList(months, "Value", "Text", dob.Month), new { width = "40px" }).ToHtmlString(),
            html.DropDownList("Year", new SelectList(years, "Value", "Text", dob.Year), new { width = "60px" }).ToHtmlString()
        );

        return new HtmlString(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
@Html.DateOfBirthFor(x => x.Dob)
```

Comment: I thought you wanted a strongly typed version of the helper? That's why I used it as it allows you to specify the property on your view model in a strongly typed way, by providing a lambda expression in your view.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by *custom binding*.

Comment: I meant to said that using above code, i can directly bind model's property as in case of @html.LabelFor(m => m.DOB).

Comment: Yes, you could use `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.DOB)` to generate a corresponding label and the `@Html.DateOfBirthFor(x => x.Dob)` custom helper to generate the 3 dropdowns. I don't understand what is the problem and what you are asking.

Comment: The error is Object reference not set to an instance of an object.In line " DateTime dob = (DateTime)ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(ex, html.ViewData).Model;".

Comment: Is your view strongly typed (you must have a `@model MyViewModel` at the top of your view)? Have you passed a model to your view (when returning this view from a controller action you need to pass an instance of the model to it: `return View(someModelInstance);`)? If you don't do that, the model will be null in the view and you will get this exception. In order to be able to use strongly typed helpers you need to have a strongly typed view.

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DateOfBirth<TModel> (this HtmlHelper<TModel>)
{ 
   // ...
}
```

Then it will be bound to that specific TModel HtmlHelper.